# How to get adjacent records?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

Not sure if this is possible (or worthwhile to do) in pure SQL, but I'll ask anyway.

Let's say I have a bunch of numbered records in my database (extra spaces for clarity):

```
2 3 4     10 11 12 13     55 56 57  91     106 107
```

Now given a number such as "11" how could I retrieve "10, 11, 12, 13"? i.e., all the adjacent records with no gap (all numbers must be +/- 1 from each other).

Is that possible? If so, how?

Comment: Could you `SELECT * WHERE ID = '10' LIMIT 4` ?

Comment: @alex that would only return one record.  The numbers in the OP are individual rows.

Comment: @Fosco Oh yes, whoops. That `=` should be `>`.

Comment: @alex the problem is: how you determine that you need a `LIMIT 4` starting at `10` given the number `11`?

Comment: In that case it's simple: `SELECT * FROM \`numbers\` WHERE MAGIC()`

Comment: @Frits: Very helpful. Now define `MAGIC()` please ;)

Comment: oracle has LEAD and LAG functions that are useful for this - not sure about mysql

Comment: This looks like the classic [gaps-and-islands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands) problem to me. You might find the other solutions in that tag useful, though strangely none of them are also tagged MySQL...

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick. `@target_id` is your target value (11 in the given example).

- Find the lower bound of the desired range — the largest value less than or equal to your target where `value-1` doesn't exist.
- Find the upper bound of the desired range — the smallest value greater than or equal to your target where `value+1` doesn't exist.
- return the rows such that *lower-bound <= x <= upper-bound*.

Easy!

```
select *
from foo t
where t.id >= ( select max(id)
                from foo x
                where x.id <= @target_id
                  and not exists ( select *
                                   from foo x1
                                   where x1.id = x.id - 1
                                 )
              )
  and t.id <= ( select min(id)
                from foo y
                where y.id >= @target_id
                  and not exists ( select *
                                   from foo y1
                                   where y1.id = y.id + 1
                                 )
              )
```

Index your id/sequence number column and I believe performance should be pretty good.

Comment: just tested. seems to work :) there's actually another condition... each record has to belong to the same user. if i'm not mistaken, i have to add this condition 5 times? one for each select?

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of anything. But if read speed is important you could consider added a field that represents the 'cluster'.
For 2, 3 and 4 the cluster would be 2. For 10, 11, 12 and 13 the cluster would be 10 and so on.

The downside is that you have to update the cluster whenever you update anything. The good part is that the arithmetic probably very easy.

Comment: If I had this cluster information it would be really easy. Problem is, our system doesn't currently record this cluster information, and....... well maybe it wouldn't be that awful to compute the cluster during each insert, then the retrievals won't be so bad.

Comment: I'm not a mysql guy, but if you maintained this "cluster value" with a trigger, are you going to run into a mutating table issue?

Comment: @eaolson: mutating table issue? it occurred to me that some of the clusters might merge, but as long as I update all the rows correctly to indicate they're now one cluster, it should work fine.

Comment: In Oracle, a row-level trigger cannot modify other rows in the table that's changing. I'm not even sure if you can select on it. Like I said, I'm a mysql guy, this may not even apply.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the context I can't comment on whether it's worthwhile or not (I'd assume not until proven otherwise,) but anything is possible!!  I'll go with pseudo-code of one method first...

Create stored procedure that takes a starting row ID, which does:

Create a temporary table of ID's.

Insert a select query into that temp table from the main table matching the Row ID.

While the number of just previously executed inserts is 0:
    Insert a select query joining the temp table with the main table
    where the absolute value of the subtraction of the ID's is equal
    to 1, and where the ID is not already in the temp table

Select the results from the temp table, joined to the main table on ID.

Given the example of 11, the first insert would insert #11, the loop would start and the second would insert #10 and #12, the third insert would only add #13, and the fourth insert would insert 0 records, ending the loop.  Then you'd get a selection from the main table of ID's 10, 11, 12, 13.

If the procedure was run with a non-existent number like #14, the loop would never start and you'd get an empty result set.

Do you think you'd be able to accomplish this or should I get writing?

Comment: Mm.. this sounds like it's leaning on the "not worthwhile" side. I can retrieve a subset of rows that I know the "cluster" is entirely contained within, and then do the rest of pruning with PHP. I think that might be the simpler solution. I was thinking I could do it in one query, or maybe a couple subqueries in pure SQL I'd do it that way... but this is OK I guess.

Comment: @Mark depends on your definition of worthwhile I guess... It wouldn't take long to write.  I could see a few variations on this: 1. looking for lower records till exhausting, then higher.  2. a recursive view (SO FUN!).

Comment: My PHP version does exactly that (1); it starts at the "current" record then goes down until it hits a gap, then restarts at the current and tries up. And I don't know much about stored procedures so I wouldn't know how to write it in SQL :D I figure retrieving a few extra records via SQL and then pruning them with PHP would be quicker than doing the pruning in pure SQL though, no?

Comment: @Mark how are you determining which rows to pull from SQL now? like ID + and - 6 or something?

Comment: not quite....the "numbers" are actually "bookings" and I know they can only be "adjacent" if they occur on the same day. +/- 10 hours (length of working day) or something would have worked just as well though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the entries are all distinct and we are in a DB that supports windowing and CTE,

```
WITH t1 AS
( SELECT id, id-row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS discrepancy FROM t )
SELECT id FROM t1 WHERE t1.discrepancy = 
  (SELECT discrepancy FROM t1 WHERE id=?);
```

I think this isn’t as fast as Nicholas’s code, but it might be worth an experiment (if your DB is capable of this query at all).

Comment: The question has been tagged `mysql`, and MySQL, to the best of my memory, doesn't support CTEs.

Comment: True; OTOH, he also asks about doing it in 'pure SQL'?!

Comment: I would interpret 'in pure SQL' as 'without additional processing in client code, but in pure SQL as supported by my RDBMS of choice', however that would just be my judging against yours. :)

Comment: @Andriy, you might be right. But maybe someone will find this page in a query who uses a different RDMBS and my typing will not have been in vain!